# rvm for Jenkins under Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat6, jenkins, rvm, continuous-integration

I've got Jenkins running under Tomcat 6. It's running as user tomcat6, with a home directory of /usr/share/tomcat6. I would like to install rvm for this user so I can use it for testing, but I can't figure out ho - is it possible to install rvm for a service user? I tried running the rvm installation script as a build step for a project, here's what I got:

> /tmp/tomcat6-tmp/hudson2846335381818356442.sh: 3: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
>   Finished: FAILURE

I also tried a multi-user installation of rvm, but I couldn't get the tomcat6 user to use any rvm commands - it seemed like it didn't recognize that rvm was installed. I'd be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bash/zsh script running in SH shell, most likely this is caused by using dash instead of bash (and linking it to /bin/sh) - it's mostly Ubuntu problem.

Make sure your scripts are ran with bash or sh which is linked to bash, it will make the script working properly.